# How to pass an argument to function in a signal?

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots

I have a function:

```
def pausing(ses):
   if ses.is_paused() == True:
      ses.start()
   else:
      ses.pause()
```

which is pausing a torrent downloading or resuming it (depends on an actual state of torrent).
I want to connect this function with a button, like this:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pausebutton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), pause)
```

But I don't know how to pass an argument **ses** to that slot (it's in a different class than the **ses**, which I want to pass).
I don't want to use global variables - how can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two methods (I am using `self.on_button` as an example function)

Something like this:

```
button1.clicked.connect(partial(self.on_button, 1))
```

And:

```
button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_button(1))
```

Comment: But where should I add this line?

Answer (score 2):

I have searched a lot of websites and I found the example here:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(parent)
        button1 = QPushButton('Button 1')
        button2 = QPushButton('Button 1')
        button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_button(1))
        button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_button(2))

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button1)
        layout.addWidget(button2)

        main_frame = QWidget()
        main_frame.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(main_frame)

    def on_button(self, n):
        print('Button {0} clicked'.format(n))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This example is from [Eli Bendersky's website](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/25/passing-extra-arguments-to-pyqt-slot/)

I hope it will help anybody who need it.